# Python np.sqrt(x-a)*np.heaviside(x,a)

Tags: python, numpy, nan, sqrt

I am trying to implement a calculation from a research paper. In that calculation, the value of a function is supposed to be

- 0, *for x<a*
- sqrt(x-a)*SOMETHING_ELSE, *for x>=a*

In my module, x and a are 1D numpy-arrays (of the same length). In my first attempt I implemented the function as

`f  = np.sqrt(x-a)*SOMETHING*np.heaviside(x,a)`

But for x<a, np.sqrt() returns NaN and even though the heaviside function returns 0 in that case, in Python `0*NaN = NaN`.

I could also replace all NaN in my resulting array with 0s afterwards but that would lead to warning outputs from numpy.sqrt() used on negative values that I would need to supress. Another solution is to treat the argument of the squareroot as an imaginary number by adding 0j and taking the real part afterwards:

`f  = np.real(np.sqrt(x-a+0j)*SOMETHING*np.heaviside(x,a))`

But I feel like both solutions are not really elegant and the second solution is unnecessarily complicated to read. Is there a more elegant way to do this in Python that I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cheat with `np.maximum` in this case to not compute the square root of negative numbers.
Moreover, please note that `np.heaviside` does not use `a` as a threshold but 0 (the second parameter is the output of the heaviside in some case). You can use `np.where` instead.

Here is an example:

```py
f = np.where(x<a, 0, np.sqrt(np.maximum(x-a, 0))*SOMETHING)
```

Note that in this specific case, the expression can be simplified and `np.where` is not even needed (because `np.sqrt(np.maximum(x-a, 0))` gives 0). Thus, you can simply write:

```py
f = np.sqrt(np.maximum(x-a, 0))*SOMETHING
```

Comment: Neat, I think ```f = np.nan_to_num(np.sqrt(x-a))*SOMETHING``` would also work (?)

Comment: @Kevin It works, but it shows a warning about "invalid value encountered in sqrt" that the OP does not want.

Comment: I like this "cheat" definitely more than my ideas so far. And thanks for the note regarding this second parameter of np.heaviside()!